# How do you pass a boolean data type as a parameter for a stored procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, boolean, informix

Say you have an existing stored procedure that accepts a single parameter, which happens to be of [the BOOLEAN Informix data type](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.esqlc.doc/ids_esqlc_0168.htm):

```
test_bool_param(BOOLEAN)
```

What would the `EXECUTE PROCEDURE` statement look like for such a stored procedure?

Here's what I've tried, and failed, with:

```
EXECUTE PROCEDURE test_bool_param('true'); -- [Error Code: -1260, SQL State: IX000]  It is not possible to convert between the specified types.
EXECUTE PROCEDURE test_bool_param('false');-- [Error Code: -1260, SQL State: IX000]  It is not possible to convert between the specified types.
EXECUTE PROCEDURE test_bool_param('TRUE'); -- [Error Code: -1260, SQL State: IX000]  It is not possible to convert between the specified types.
EXECUTE PROCEDURE test_bool_param('FALSE');-- [Error Code: -1260, SQL State: IX000]  It is not possible to convert between the specified types.
EXECUTE PROCEDURE test_bool_param(true);   -- [Error Code:  -201, SQL State: 42000]  A syntax error has occurred.
EXECUTE PROCEDURE test_bool_param(false);  -- [Error Code:  -201, SQL State: 42000]  A syntax error has occurred.
EXECUTE PROCEDURE test_bool_param(TRUE);   -- [Error Code:  -201, SQL State: 42000]  A syntax error has occurred.
EXECUTE PROCEDURE test_bool_param(FALSE);  -- [Error Code:  -201, SQL State: 42000]  A syntax error has occurred.
EXECUTE PROCEDURE test_bool_param(1);      -- [Error Code:  -674, SQL State: IX000]  Routine (test_bool_param) can not be resolved.
EXECUTE PROCEDURE test_bool_param(0);      -- [Error Code:  -674, SQL State: IX000]  Routine (test_bool_param) can not be resolved.
EXECUTE PROCEDURE test_bool_param('\1');   -- [Error Code: -1260, SQL State: IX000]  It is not possible to convert between the specified types.
EXECUTE PROCEDURE test_bool_param('\0');   -- [Error Code: -1260, SQL State: IX000]  It is not possible to convert between the specified types.
EXECUTE PROCEDURE test_bool_param('t');    -- [Error Code: -1260, SQL State: IX000]  It is not possible to convert between the specified types.
EXECUTE PROCEDURE test_bool_param('f');    -- [Error Code: -1260, SQL State: IX000]  It is not possible to convert between the specified types.
EXECUTE PROCEDURE test_bool_param('T');    -- [Error Code: -1260, SQL State: IX000]  It is not possible to convert between the specified types.
EXECUTE PROCEDURE test_bool_param('F');    -- [Error Code: -1260, SQL State: IX000]  It is not possible to convert between the specified types.
EXECUTE PROCEDURE test_bool_param(t);      -- [Error Code:  -201, SQL State: 42000]  A syntax error has occurred.
EXECUTE PROCEDURE test_bool_param(f);      -- [Error Code:  -201, SQL State: 42000]  A syntax error has occurred.
EXECUTE PROCEDURE test_bool_param(T);      -- [Error Code:  -201, SQL State: 42000]  A syntax error has occurred.
EXECUTE PROCEDURE test_bool_param(F);      -- [Error Code:  -201, SQL State: 42000]  A syntax error has occurred.
EXECUTE PROCEDURE test_bool_param(\1);     -- [Error Code:  -202, SQL State: IX000]  An illegal character has been found in the statement.
EXECUTE PROCEDURE test_bool_param(\0);     -- [Error Code:  -202, SQL State: IX000]  An illegal character has been found in the statement.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These `EXECUTE PROCEDURE` calls *do* actually succeed:

```
EXECUTE PROCEDURE test_bool_param('t');     -- Result set fetched - SUCCESS
EXECUTE PROCEDURE test_bool_param('f');     -- Result set fetched - FAILURE
EXECUTE PROCEDURE test_bool_param('T');     -- Result set fetched - SUCCESS
EXECUTE PROCEDURE test_bool_param('F');     -- Result set fetched - FAILURE
```

But only when any checks in the stored procedure also compare to one of `'t'`, `'f'`, `'T'`, or `'F'`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test_bool_param
(in_param BOOLEAN)
RETURNING VARCHAR(8)
IF (in_param = 't') THEN
        RETURN 'SUCCESS';
ELSE
        RETURN 'FAILURE';
END IF;
END PROCEDURE;
```

Comment: From the documentation: `You can compare two BOOLEAN values to test for equality or inequality. You can also compare a BOOLEAN value to the Boolean literals 't' and 'f'. BOOLEAN values are not case-sensitive; 't' is equivalent to 'T' and 'f' to 'F'.` , So yes, it works for the literals used in your successful executions of the procedure.

Comment: @LuísMarques What documentation is that from? The official IBM documentation linked in the question only mentions `'\0'` and `'\1'`, neither of which work.

Comment: It is actually in the `Guide to SQL: Reference`, data types section: [Description of Data Types](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqlr.doc/ids_sqr_099.htm)